# How can I pre randomize rows in MySQL using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

im new here and would like to ask how can i make this line of code work in vb.net?

```
Dim Query As String = "UPDATE r1questions SET rownum = (@rownum := @rownum+1) ORDER BY RAND()"
```

The code is always returning an error, i know the "@" sign should include a parameter but i got this code in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046003/getting-random-data-from-a-mysql-database-but-not-repeating-data/24047638#24047638)
and works ok in Mysql itself, but not in Vb.net.

EDIT: This is the error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':= rownum+1) ORDER BY RAND()' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do somthing like this

```
UPDATE r1questions SET rownum = RAND() * 1000
```

Comment: Thank you for response. Well I already tried that but that problem is sometime the numbers are repeated. Im trying to avoid repetition. The link that I provided actually gave the right code I just cant find a way to make it work in VB.net